# Android Studio start many instance of java.exe until run out of ram

Tags: android, android-studio

Recently I encountered this error of Android Studio 4.1 . It start many instance of java.exe (OpenJDK Platform binary) until run out of RAM (I have 10gb of RAM).

[image]

I cannot  sync, build projects. I have uninstall it and reinstall Android Studio 4.1 but the same thing happened. This is the error message I receive from AS after 10 minutes it build (normally only takes about 2 mins) : **The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection.**

Does anyone have this error and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: I have the exact problem, Just now 100 openJDk platform binary processes were created, that keeps happening till the RAM gets full, Have you found a solution for this problem??

Comment: @MustafaShahoud restart the whole laptop wont work for me so I shutdown and wait a little bit and I turn it back on. Then it worked.

Comment: Yeah I usually do so, but that won't fix it permanently.

Comment: For me the problem seems to be in the Mobile hotspot, I have turned it off, since that time the problem has been disappeared.

Comment: Mobile Hotspot was the problem for me too. Thank you @MustafaShahoud .

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have found the problem. I use Mobile Hotspot on Windows 10, switched it off and the Gradle deamon will run normal again.

Comment: you are my hero bro!

Comment: it's work, but i need permanent solution.

Comment: hmm, it took me 3 days to find this answer

Comment: can be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65448500/12980819

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was using VPN connection and problem solved after disconnecting VPN and restart Android studio IDE!!!

Comment: This case happened multiple times and after disconnecting problem solved!!!

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize that VPN can create such trouble until I fixed it by uninstalling VPN software.
I have been trying to uninstall Android Studio and Java more than 3 times but got no luck until I read that VPN also can rise this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was using adb Wi-Fi plugin to run app through Wi-Fi network, for that I am using hotspot in windows 10 that causing opening many instance of java.exe (OpenJDK Platform binary).

**Only Solution worked for me was turning off the Hotspot.**