# Android studio OpenJDK platform binary problem it repeats up to 80 or more

Tags: android-studio

[image]

Hi, since yesterday I got this problem with Android Studio, it gets open "JDK platform binary" many times ( I didn't let it to goes on ), and my laptop will be not responding

how can I solve this? any thought?

Comment: Here's a duplicate question with more (or less) information: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64656341/android-studio-start-many-instance-of-java-exe-until-run-out-of-ram

Answer (score 7):

Check If Your Hotspot is on. Turn that off, Kill Your android Studio Process from Task Manager and open again. I don't why but it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: That's really weird but it fixed the problem. I was going nuts because of this. I thought I needed to upgrade my RAM.

Comment: Exactly! So weird. Worked for me too

Answer (score 2):

I can't find the reason why there are so many process `java.exe` in Task Manager but there is a quick solution for that problem.

make a `kill.bat` file with content as bellow and add to your PATH

```
taskkill /IM "java.exe" /F
```

And use command `kill` to kill all process `java.exe` when you want.

Answer (score 0):

If it's still opening too many times without turn on the hotspot, run the android studio as administrator. It fixed this issue for me.

**Update**

After that still not fixed. use `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms512m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8` in the `gradle.properties` instead of `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8`. And **do not share your connection**.
[image: Do not share the connection]

That would be fix the issue permanently.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to kill all processes and turn of the wifi hostpot it will solve the problem