# Flutter - FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. - Unable to start the daemon process. - Android Studio - VSCode

Tags: flutter, android-studio, visual-studio-code, runtime-error

Whenever I try to run a flutter app using flutter run -v i get the below error. If i don't use the terminal and just click run the running gradle task keeps running and nothing happens.

I tried:

1. changed in gradle.properties `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m  => org.gradle.jvmargs:-Xmx1024m`
2. deleted .gradle file
3. reset my laptop

what can i do?

flutter run -v
[image: Error in terminal]

Flutter doctor
[image: flutter doctor]

*flutter build apk -v

```
[  +95 ms] executing: [C:\Flutter\flutter/] git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1
--pretty=format:%H
[  +73 ms] Exit code 0 from: git -c log.showSignature=false log -n 1 --pretty=format:%H
[        ] 4d7946a68d26794349189cf21b3f68cc6fe61dcb
[   +1 ms] executing: [C:\Flutter\flutter/] git tag --points-at
4d7946a68d26794349189cf21b3f68cc6fe61dcb
[  +93 ms] Exit code 0 from: git tag --points-at 4d7946a68d26794349189cf21b3f68cc6fe61dcb
[        ] 2.0.3
[  +45 ms] executing: [C:\Flutter\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[  +32 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref --symbolic @{u}
[        ] origin/stable
[        ] executing: [C:\Flutter\flutter/] git ls-remote --get-url origin
[  +30 ms] Exit code 0 from: git ls-remote --get-url origin
[        ] https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
[  +82 ms] executing: [C:\Flutter\flutter/] git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[  +27 ms] Exit code 0 from: git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
[        ] stable
[  +85 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidGenSnapshotArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[   +2 ms] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[  +59 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MaterialFonts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'GradleWrapper' is not required, skipping update.
[   +4 ms] Artifact Instance of 'AndroidInternalBuildArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterWebSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterSdk' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'WindowsEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxEngineArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'LinuxFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'MacOSFuchsiaSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerSDKArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FlutterRunnerDebugSymbols' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[        ] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'IosUsbArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'FontSubsetArtifacts' is not required, skipping update.
[   +1 ms] Artifact Instance of 'PubDependencies' is not required, skipping update.
[  +48 ms] Skipping pub get: version match.
[ +133 ms] Generating
C:\Users\Salma\Desktop\Grad\flutter_app\android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPlugin
Registrant.java
[ +396 ms] Building without sound null safety
[   +1 ms] For more information see https://dart.dev/null-safety/unsound-null-safety
[  +25 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'...
[   +8 ms] Using gradle from C:\Users\Salma\Desktop\Grad\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat.
[   +5 ms] C:\Users\Salma\Desktop\Grad\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat mode: 33279 rwxrwxrwx.
[  +10 ms] executing: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[ +187 ms] Exit code 0 from: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java -version
[   +2 ms] openjdk version "1.8.0_242-release"
           OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
           OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b01, mixed mode)
[   +3 ms] executing: [C:\Users\Salma\Desktop\Grad\flutter_app\android/]
C:\Users\Salma\Desktop\Grad\flutter_app\android\gradlew.bat -Pverbose=true
-Ptarget-platform=android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64 -Ptarget=lib\main.dart
-Ptrack-widget-creation=true -Ptree-shake-icons=true assembleRelease
[+2795 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 100 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+2481 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 101 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[+2502 ms] Starting a Gradle Daemon, 102 busy Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details
[  +23 ms] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[   +4 ms] * What went wrong:
[   +2 ms] Unable to start the daemon process.
[   +1 ms] This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
[   +1 ms] For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
[   +1 ms] Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at
https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
[   +1 ms] Process command line: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java.exe -Xmx1024m
-Dfile.encoding=windows-1252 -Duser.country=US -Duser.language=en -Duser.variant -cp
C:\Users\Salma\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-6.7-all\cuy9mc7upwgwgeb72wkcrupxe\gradle-6.7\lib\gradle-
launcher-6.7.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 6.7
[   +1 ms] Please read the following process output to find out more:
[   +1 ms] -----------------------
[        ] Error occurred during initialization of VM
[        ] Could not reserve enough space for object heap
[        ] * Try:
[        ] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to
get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[   +1 ms] * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[  +30 ms] Running Gradle task 'assembleRelease'... (completed in 8.1s)
[   +8 ms] "flutter apk" took 8,820ms.
[   +8 ms] Gradle task assembleRelease failed with exit code 1
[   +3 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:10:3)
           #1      buildGradleApp (package:flutter_tools/src/android/gradle.dart:411:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      _AndroidBuilderImpl.buildApk
(package:flutter_tools/src/android/android_builder.dart:101:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #3      BuildApkCommand.runCommand
(package:flutter_tools/src/commands/build_apk.dart:103:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #4      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1157:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #5      FlutterCommand.run.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:1009:27)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #6      AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #7      AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #8      CommandRunner.runCommand (package:args/command_runner.dart:197:13)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #9      FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand.<anonymous closure>
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:278:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #10     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #11     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #12     FlutterCommandRunner.runCommand
           (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command_runner.dart:234:5)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #13     run.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:64:9)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #14     run.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter_tools/runner.dart:62:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #15     AppContext.run.<anonymous closure>
(package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:150:19)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #16     AppContext.run (package:flutter_tools/src/base/context.dart:149:12)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #17     runInContext (package:flutter_tools/src/context_runner.dart:73:10)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #18     main (package:flutter_tools/executable.dart:90:3)
           <asynchronous suspension>          
[ +117 ms] ensureAnalyticsSent: 113ms
[   +4 ms] Running shutdown hooks
[   +1 ms] Shutdown hooks complete
[   +1 ms] exiting with code 1
```

Comment: You don't have enough computer ram. I'd suggest switching to vscode and also upgrading your ram to at least 8gb

Comment: @Uni, my ram 8gb (7.71 gb usable), for vscode it give an alert this window is no longer responding for flutter run

Comment: That's weird. Could you post the output of flutter run --verbose?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that OpenJDK platform binary opens many instances which eats up my memory,
I found out about this problem from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65437523/android-studio-openjdk-platform-binary-problem-it-repeats-up-to-80-or-more) and  [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66860600/10817272) said to turn off the Hotspot and that did work.
Also restarting your laptop might work for some cases but not all.

I don't know how the Hotspot is the problem or in what way is it connected to OpenJDK if anyone has an explanation please comment it.

Comment: Yes! It worked for me too...

Answer (score 1):

Please always post your error logs as text and not images.

1- run `flutter clean` then build again.

2- Are you running it on a simulator or physical device?

3- If on a simulator, increase that devices virtual ram. Better more, delete the simulator and create a new one.

4- If still doesn't work, run `flutter upgrade`.

5- Can you build the file as an APK? in other words, not to run on a device?

6- Please post the output of `flutter build apk -v`.

Comment: I am running it on a physical device

Comment: It could mean your device is out of memeory. Kindly post the output of `flutter build apk -v` , and we can see if your app builds or not, ro rule out it's an issue with your computer or configuration Vs simulator\phone issues.

Comment: I added ```flutter build apk -v``` output

Comment: @salma.m it's apparently a computer issue, something is eating up your memory. Try restarting your computer freshly, close everything out and open open your code, then try to build it. What operating system are you using?

Comment: I am using windows 10.

Comment: Did a fresh restart of your device help?

Comment: Yes the error is no longer there but it still gets stuck at running gradle task 'assembleDebug'

Comment: @salma.m this means progress.is the output of `flutter build apk -v` the same? How long have you been building?

Comment: Flutter build apk -v : ```Unable to allocate 49152KB bitmaps for parallel garbage collection for the requested 1572864KB heap```

Comment: Flutter doctor -v: [!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\Salma\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    X Could not determine java version

Answer (score 0):

### I have tried these solutions that will work in every case:

**1. Windows Bug >** Very Common issue caused by this BUG, try to turn off the Mobile Hotspot from settings before running the app.

**2.** Try to **Close** Extra software that are running in your PC, close chrome if needed, **Invalidate cache and Restart** the Android Studio. then **Flutter Clean**, **Flutter Pub Get**, **Run App**.

**3.** Try to Delete `.gradle` folder from android folder, **Invalidate Cache and Restart** Android Studio, Wait for Indexing and Then only start Building App.

---

**4.** If no One Worked from Above then simply edit `gradle.properties` file then,

find this line: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536M`

replace it with this: `org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024M`

Answer (score 0):

install the latest version of flutter sdk

link:
https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows