# Flutter Daemon failed to start

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

I am getting this warning every time I open `VS code`. Are there any ways to solve this problem? Thank you.

[image]

I added the log of this warning. I have tried **flutter clean** and **flutter doctor** and everything is fine, but this warning still appear every time I open VS Code. I also faced a problem where VS Code show no device no the status bar but when I run **flutter devices** it shows that there are 3 active devices. Thank you.

```
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\windows\system32
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\windows\system32\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\windows
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\windows\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\windows\System32\Wbem
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\windows\System32\Wbem\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\PuTTY\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\PuTTY\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\nodejs\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\dotnet\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\dotnet\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Go\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Roaming\npm
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Roaming\npm\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\mosquitto
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\mosquitto\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.8.14\sbin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Handle
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Handle\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\go\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Chrome Driver Win32
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Chrome Driver Win32\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\flutter
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\flutter
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]     Found at C:\Users\nurfa\flutter
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path C:\Users\nurfa\flutter for flutter.bat
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info] Searching for dart.exe
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]     Looking for dart.exe in:
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\windows\system32
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\windows\system32\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\windows
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\windows\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\windows\System32\Wbem
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\windows\System32\Wbem\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\system32\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2018a\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Brackets\command\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\PuTTY\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\PuTTY\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\nodejs\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\nodejs\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\dotnet\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\dotnet\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Go\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Scripts\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Roaming\npm
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Roaming\npm\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\Vim\vim82\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\mosquitto
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\mosquitto\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.8.14\sbin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files (x86)\GnuWin32\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Handle
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\Handle\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2021.1\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2021.1.1\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\go\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Chrome Driver Win32
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Chrome Driver Win32\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\13\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]     Found at:
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]     Candidate paths to be post-filtered:
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]         C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]     Found at C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info]     Returning SDK path C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk for dart.exe
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info] Experiment random number is 55 for experiement 'lsp-default'. Experiment is enabled for <= 100
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info] Experiment 'lsp-default' is activating (not first time)
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info] !! PLEASE REVIEW THIS LOG FOR SENSITIVE INFORMATION BEFORE SHARING !!

Dart Code extension: 3.25.1
Flutter extension: 3.25.0 (not activated)

App: Visual Studio Code
Version: 1.59.0
Platform: win

Workspace type: Flutter
Analyzer type: LSP
Multi-root?: false

Dart SDK:
    Loc: C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
    Ver: 2.13.4
Flutter SDK:
    Loc: C:\Users\nurfa\flutter
    Ver: 2.2.3

HTTP_PROXY: undefined
NO_PROXY: undefined
[12:07:27 pm] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] Spawning C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\flutter.bat with args ["--no-sound-null-safety","daemon"]
[12:07:27 pm] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ..  in C:\Users\nurfa\flutter
[12:07:27 pm] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ..  with {"toolEnv":{"FLUTTER_HOST":"VSCode","PUB_ENVIRONMENT":"vscode.dart-code"}}
[12:07:27 pm] [FlutterDaemon] [Info]     PID: 39588
[12:07:27 pm] [FlutterDaemon] [Info] ==> [{"id":"1","method":"emulator.getEmulators"}]
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info] Spawning C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat with args ["global","list"]
[12:07:27 pm] [CommandProcesses] [Info] (PROC 12148) Logging data for process...
[12:07:27 pm] [Analyzer] [Info] Spawning C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe with args ["C:\\Users\\nurfa\\flutter\\bin\\cache\\dart-sdk\\bin\\snapshots\\analysis_server.dart.snapshot","--lsp","--client-id=VS-Code","--client-version=3.25.1"]
[12:07:27 pm] [Analyzer] [Info]     PID: 63952
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info] Activating Flutter extension for Flutter project...
[12:07:27 pm] [General] [Info] Extension:Startup timing: 58503ms
[12:07:27 pm] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> Content-Length: 4900
[12:07:27 pm] [Analyzer] [Info] ==> {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":0,"method":"initialize","params":{"processId":39588,"clientInfo":{"name":"Visual Studio Code","version":"1.59.0"},"locale":"en-us","rootPath":"c:\\Users\\nurfa\\Desktop\\tracker_fisherman","rootUri":"file:///c%3A/Users/nurfa/Desktop/tracker_fisherman","capabilities":{"workspace":{"applyEdit":true,"workspaceEdit":{"documentChanges":true,"resourceOperations":["create","rename","delete"],"failureHandling":"textOnlyTransactional","normalizesLineEndings":true,"changeAnnotati…
[12:07:28 pm] [General] [Info] !! PLEASE REVIEW THIS LOG FOR SENSITIVE INFORMATION BEFORE SHARING !!

Dart Code extension: 3.25.1
Flutter extension: 3.25.0 (activated)

App: Visual Studio Code
Version: 1.59.0
Platform: win

Workspace type: Flutter
Analyzer type: LSP
Multi-root?: false

Dart SDK:
    Loc: C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk
    Ver: 2.13.4
Flutter SDK:
    Loc: C:\Users\nurfa\flutter
    Ver: 2.2.3

HTTP_PROXY: undefined
NO_PROXY: undefined
[12:07:28 pm] [CommandProcesses] [Info] (PROC 12148) devtools 2.5.0
[12:07:28 pm] [General] [Info] Found 0 folders requiring "pub get":
[12:07:28 pm] [CommandProcesses] [Info] (PROC 12148) exited (0, null)
[12:07:28 pm] [CommandProcesses] [Info] (PROC 12148) closed (0, null)
[12:07:28 pm] [General] [Info] devtools version 2.5.0 appears to be latest so returning Valid
[12:07:28 pm] [DevTools] [Info] Spawning C:\Users\nurfa\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat with args ["global","run","devtools","--machine","--try-ports","10","--allow-embedding"]
[12:07:28 pm] [DevTools] [Info] ..  with {"toolEnv":{"FLUTTER_HOST":"VSCode","PUB_ENVIRONMENT":"vscode.dart-code"}}
[12:07:28 pm] [DevTools] [Info]     PID: 39588
[12:07:35 pm] [Analyzer] [Info] <== Content-Length: 384
Content-Type: application/vscode-jsonrpc; charset=utf-8

{"id":0,"jsonrpc":"2.0","result":{"capabilities":{"executeCommandProvider":{"commands":["edit.sortMembers","edit.organizeImports","edit.sendWorkspaceEdit","refactor.perform"],"workDoneProgress":true},"workspaceSymbolProvider":true,"workspace":{"workspaceFolders":{"supported":true,"changeNotifications":true}}},"serverInfo":{"name":"Dart SDK LSP Analysis Server","version":"2.13.4"}}}
[12:07:35 pm] [DevTools] [Info] <== {"event":"server.started","method":"server.started","params":{"host":"127.0.0.1","port":9100,"pid":61224,"protocolVersion":"1.1.0"}}
```

Comment: It would help to show the log.

Comment: are you using an emulator?

Comment: @JahidulIslam I am using physical device

Comment: @ObsidianAge I have show the log

Answer (score 9):

Search for **dart.flutterAdditionalArgs** in your vs code settings.

and remove args against it.

Comment: I removed --no-sound-null-safety flutter additional arg and this solved the problem

Answer (score 1):

**Ive resolved this error with the below Steps:**

1. Go to **{C://Users/{Name}/.gradle}** - Delete the **.gradle** file.
2. Then Download and install the same flutter and dart SDK version in some other location and set the environment variables.

**`Example:`**

`Environment variables Before  : ("D:\FlutterExtractedFiles\flutter\bin") ("D:\FlutterExtractedFiles\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin")`

`Environment variables After : ("C:\edgedownloads\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable\flutter\bin") ("C:\edgedownloads\flutter_windows_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin")`

3. Then kindly check the android studio Event Log

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66814616/flutter-failure-build-failed-with-an-exception-unable-to-start-the-daemon) that I have edited.

Please always post your error logs as text and not images.

1- run `flutter clean` then `flutter doctor` and build again.

2- Are you running it on a simulator or physical device?

3- If on a simulator, increase that device's virtual ram. Better more, delete the simulator and create a new one.

4- If still doesn't work, run a `flutter upgrade`.

5- Can you build the file as an `APK`? in other words, not to run on a device?

6- Please post the output of flutter build `apk -v`.

Comment: I not sure is it because of VS code issue, when I run flutter run in command it's able to run.

Answer (score 0):

do these general steps:

1. run `flutter clean`
2. run `flutter doctor`
3. if you are using an emulator make sure it has enough space and also try to wipe its data and cold reboot.
4. then rerun your project.

Comment: I have tried this before I ask for help but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

If the above did'nt work then go to Android Studio , Uninstall all the sdk tools you have installed ,then reinstall it

Answer (score 0):

### Put Explicit Web Port in Profile Not Settings

If you are experiencing the `Flutter Daemon failed to Start error` as I did only after setting an explicit port for web view:

1. Delete the --web-port line in VS Code Settings (`Ctrl-,`):

```
DELETE->> "dart.flutterAdditionalArgs": ["--web-port", "4593"]
```

2. Open .vscode/launch.json  and add the port to the "args" property in your launch profile, for example:

```
{  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "launch-chrome",
      "cwd": "cli",
      "request": "launch",
      "type": "dart",
ADD->> "args": [
        "--web-port", "4395", "-dchrome"
      ],
      "program": "${file}"

    }
  ]
}
```

I was developing for the Web and per this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61784218/2205849) specified the port explicitly in VS Code Settings and found that for some reason Flutter Daemon doesn't like this on startup.

The port is still honored but no Flutter Daemon failure error.

Using Windows 10.

Comment: It didn't work could you help me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same struggle and non of the answers above worked for me. After searching for quite a long time I noticed that some permissions are handled differently by default with the latest macOS versions.
After fixing the permission issues and restarting VS Code it started working just fine.

In my case I had to run these commands in the VS Code terminal:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/[MYUSERNAME]/Documents/flutter
```

(change the path accordingly where you downloaded or cloned the flutter sdk - but use the parent folder and not "/bin" like in your paths file)

and secondly:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/[MYUSERNAME]/.pub-cache
```

Hopefully this helps someone out there, too :-)

Comment: `chown` changes file ownership, you state (if I read you right) *default handling of permissions differs* - can you spell out the connection?

Comment: @greybeard Yeah I meant the default access permissions of newly created folders in these mac directories seems to be different than with older versions of it. Back then it was the default that every user could also write into this directories while they can now only read. Due to the fact that the flutter deamon needs to write into the named folders it failed to start and after changing the ownership/permission it is not an issue anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Try ReDownloading android Platform tools

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

For me, this works in the mac

`sudo chown -R $(whoami) /Users/(user-name)/.config/flutter/tool_state`