# Android Studio : Too many Open JDK Platform Binary process

Tags: java, android, android-studio, ram

I usually get this problem on my Android Studio.

[image]

Gradle often sync failed with this error. When I open Task Manager I could see too many Open JDK Platform Binary running like the below.

[image]

My RAM usage goes up to 100% due to this ( 8GB RAM), when I restart my laptop, it disappear and my Gradle will sync successfully. How can I fix this?

Comment: Kill some of them in Task Manager!

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @Thirasha No man, I still face to this problem

Comment: @NguyễnVươngThanhTuấn finally I found a solution. check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68330256/12277320)

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue by turning off the Mobile Hotspot in windows 10. I don't know what's the reason but it worked for me. While building gradle make sure Mobile Hotspot is turned off.

Answer (score 0):

Turning of Mobile Hotspot in Windows 10 Worked for me Too.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).